# Understanding the Stucture of a Vue Project (vuetify)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm new to Vue and Vuetify, I'm just trying to figure out the structure I should have when writing my code. I'm starting to get a bit confused with the differences between v-layout and v-flex.

Here is my current structure: I'm trying to position the flex xs8 (with the room type) next to the flex xs2 (with paragraph 'test').

```
<v-container ma-6 grid-list-xl>

            <v-layout>

                <v-flex md8 xs12>

                    <!-- My spaces -->
                    <v-layout v-for="space in spaces" v-if="space.id === selected" :key="space.id" row wrap>

                        <!-- The rooms -->
                        <v-flex v-for="room in space.rooms" :key="room.id" xs12 md6>

                            <!-- A room -->
                            <v-card class="card-round">

                                <!-- Image -->
                                    <v-carousel>
                                        <v-carousel-item v-for="image in room.images" :src="image.src" :key="image.id"></v-carousel-item>
                                    </v-carousel>

                                    <!-- Information -->
                                    <v-layout row wrap>

                                        <v-card-text primary-title>

                                            <v-flex xs8>
                                                <p> {{ room.type }} </p>
                                                <h3 class="headline"> {{ room.name }} </h3>
                                            </v-flex>

                                            <v-flex xs2>
                                                <p>test</p>
                                            </v-flex>

                                        </v-card-text>

                                    </v-layout>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-layout>
                </v-flex>

                <v-flex hidden-md-and-down>
                    <p>temp sidebar</p>
                </v-flex>

            </v-layout>

</v-container>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want any elements to be displayed side by side (inline), put them inside `v-layout`

```
<v-layout>

  <v-flex xs8>
    <p> {{ room.type }} </p>
    <h3 class="headline"> {{ room.name }} </h3>
  </v-flex>

  <v-flex xs2>
    <p>test</p>
  </v-flex>

</v-layout>
```

Comment: Sweet thanks, just moving the v-layout into the card element fixed it!

Comment: @Otto no problem. Btw, to address you question above, yes you can put `v-layout` inside `v-flex`. Think about this way - If you need some elements to be display side by side, just wrap them with a `v-layout`

Answer (score 3):

The `<v-layout>` tag component just represent the flex box (basically, a div with a `display: flex;` CSS rule).

The `<v-flex>` tags components that you put inside the `<v-layout>` tag are the elements of your flexbox (the ones that you can customize the "grow/shrink behavior" with the `flex` CSS rule)

That's it.

Comment: Ok cool thanks! However can I put a <v-layout> inside a <v-flex>, like I did above? Or should i just put <v-layout> and inside that a <v-flex> and then a <v-flex> in there?

Comment: Yes you can, this is nothing more than a div inside an other one in this case